# Logstash not working with allow_time_override and getting data loss influxdb

Tags: logstash, influxdb, data-loss

I am facing data loss issue with logstash version 5.2 with influxdb output pluggin.

My logstash configs are:

```
filter {
  grok {
 patterns_dir => ["/etc/logstash/patterns"]
      match => { "message" => "%{NGINXACCESSBLOG}"}
      if [type] == "nginx-access-router" {
    ruby { code => "event.set('epoc', event.get('@timestamp').to_i)" }
    date {
        match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MMM/YYYY:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
    target => "newdate"
      }

    mutate { convert => [ "request_time", "float" ] }
    if ![response] {
      mutate { add_field => ["response", "nil"] }
    }
}
}
}


output {

  if [type] == "nginx-access" {

        influxdb {
      host => "localhost"
      port => 8086
      user => "admin"
      password => "XXX"
      db => "xx"
      allow_time_override => true
      retention_policy => "XX"
      measurement => "XXXX"
      enable_metric => false
      send_as_tags => ["response"]
      data_points => {

        "response" => "%{[response]}"

    "timestamp" => "%{[epoc]}"
        "time" => "%{[epoc]}"


     }
     coerce_values => {
        "request_time"   => "float"
    }
}
}
}
```

Note: I have checked in debug log that all received log lines are successfully parsed with grok pattern.

Then why getting more then 50% data loss.

Some solution i tried:
 As per 
https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-influxdb/issues/69

I tried to use "allow_time_override" as above mentioned configuration but logstash stop pushing data to influx and getting nothing in error log file.

Answer (score 0):

After lots of tracing step by step able to find the root cause and fix of data loss issue as i posted yesterday.

Issue root cause is:

Influxdb overrides duplicate timestamp

Solution: override time as microsecond